# What is the name of this tower defense game?

Tags: game-identification

While in a children's hospital, I played a fun tower defense game on a Microsoft Surface with my son. I'm wondering if anyone can name this game, so that I can find out if this game, or any similar game, is available on another platform.

The game consisted of a series of rounds, in which a stream of invading space ships would attempt to make it to earth. In order to defend the planet, each of the players (one to four) would place satellites for defense.

Once placed, satellites could not be moved, though they could be upgraded or sold back. Satellites would automatically detect invading ships within their range and fire at them. Based on the hits satellites achieve, the player placing the satellite would can money with which you could buy or upgrade satellites.

Wish I could give a screenshot ... hoping that this description sounds familiar to someone.

Here is a link to a brief video of the game:

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The name of the game is [Galactic Alliance](http://news.softpedia.com/news/Microsoft-Surface-Galactic-Alliance-Tower-Defense-Game-144183.shtml).

Though it doesn't appear to be purchasable in the Microsoft Store, it can be purchased [for the iPad](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/galactic-alliance/id396932298?mt=8).  Additionally, the sequel, [Galactic Alliance 2](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/galactic-alliance-2/id491354805?mt=8), was released for the iPad in 2012.

Comment: I missed by 20 minutes, but had fun researching. Here's how it went down: The video's user (nomisxid) posted this video 3 years ago just after PAX 2010 videos. There are 2 PAX conventions in 2010, but other videos were in Seattle so I just assumed. Researching Seattle PAX PRIME 2010 and Surface turned up Vectorform as Surface Game developers. Fiddling around on their blog turned up [this article](http://blog.vectorform.com/2011/01/06/surface-2-0-meets-galactic-alliance-hd/) about Galactic Alliance HD